# python lambda function syntax error

Tags: python, lambda

```
def get_cluster_rows():
for path, rows in itertools.groupby(get_word_rows(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    wordcounts = [(w,c) for _,w,c in rows]
    wordcounts.sort(key=lambda (w,c): -c)

    yield path, len(wordcounts), wordcounts[:50], wordcounts
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax:

```
wordcounts.sort(key=lambda (w,c): -c)
                           ^
```

how to write lambda function with (w,c)?

Comment: Remove brackets

Answer (score 2):

You should remove brackets:

```
wordcounts.sort(key=lambda w, c: -c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply list your comma separated parameters without any brackets like:

```
f = lambda x,y: x+y
f(2,3)
5
```